# Error (10500): VHDL syntax error------expecting "(", or an identifier ("others" is a reserved keyword), or unary operator

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

I copied the code from my textbook, but there are some errors which is not contained in my book.

This are the errors:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Moore_State is
port(
    CLK: in STD_LOGIC;
    S: in STD_LOGIC;
    FB: in STD_LOGIC;
    BACK_OUT: out STD_LOGIC;
    FORWARD_OUT: out STD_LOGIC
    );
end Moore_State;

architecture Moore1_arch of Moore_State is
type StateType is (idle,ready,back,forward);
signal state:StateType;
begin
Process(CLK)
begin
if(CLK'event and CLK='1') then

case state is

when idle=>
        if S='1' then state<=ready;
        else state<=idle;
        end if;
when ready=>
        if FB='0' then state<=back;
        else state<=forward;
        end if;
when back=>
        if S='1' then state<=idle;
        else state<=back;
        end if;
when forward=>
        if S='1' then state<=idle;
        else state<=forward;
        end if;

        end case;
    end if;
end Process;

with state select
    BACK_OUT <='1' when back,
            '0' when others;
    FORWARD_OUT <='1' when forward,
            '0' when others;

end Moore1_arch;
```

and the error messages appear in the last paragraph:

1.Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at VHDL1.vhd(48) near text ",";  expecting ";"

2.Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at VHDL1.vhd(49) near text "others";  expecting "(", or an identifier ("others" is a reserved keyword), or  unary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `with-select` statement in the second part:

```
with state select
    BACK_OUT     <= '1' when back,
                    '0' when others;

with state select
    FORWARD_OUT  <= '1' when forward,
                    '0' when others;
```

Comment: @ZHOU If you find the answer helpful, please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted.